# I am new to ASP.NET and C# I am creating a web based application to enter data into a table from one page and access from other page using same table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have page Add Item which adds item to table ***foalmaster***
Right now I can successfully add items to the table using  ***Add Item*** page

I have another page ***Masterlist*** which should ideally fetch data from ***foalmaster*** table and display the same data in a tabular format
Presently I am not able to see any data being populated into the ***Masterlist*** page table inspite of data being added to table ***foalmaster***

Any help would be greatly appreciated
First time here...Pls forgive for any rookie mistakes
Using Visual Studio 2022
Thanks in advance

Being new to this area I was not able to apply much troubleshooting
My code is as follows:

1. Add Item.cshtml.cs

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace PCERM.Pages
    {
        public class Add_ItemModel : PageModel
        {
            public void OnGet()
            {

            }

            [BindProperty]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
            [Display(Name = "Item ID*")]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
            public string Itemid { get; set; } = "";


            [BindProperty]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
            [Display(Name = "Serial No*")]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
            public string Serno { get; set; } = "";


            [BindProperty]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
            [Display(Name = "Serial Name*")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
            public string Sername { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Quantity*")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
        public string Qty { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Unit*")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
        public string Unit { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Price of Last Purchase*")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
        public string Lastprice { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Vendor Name*")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Item ID must be a number")]
        public string Vendorname { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Department*")]
        public string Department { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Section*")]
        public string Section { get; set; } = "";


        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Category*")]
        public string Category { get; set; } = "";

        public List<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value="Electrical",Text="Electrical" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="Engineering",Text="Engineering" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="Executive",Text="Executive" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="Logistics",Text="Logistics" },

        };

        public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value="1",Text="Less Than Rs.20000" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="2",Text="Rs.20000 to Rs. 2.5 lakh" },
         
        };

        public List<SelectListItem> SectionList { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value="PGD",Text="PGD" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="NDC",Text="NDC" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="IT",Text="IT" },
            new SelectListItem {Value="GEN",Text="GEN" },

        };

        public string Successmsg { get; set; } = "";
        public string Errormsg { get; set; } = "";



        public void OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Errormsg = "Please Fill All Fields";
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PCERM;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT foalmaster ON;" + "INSERT INTO foalmaster" +
                        "(Itemid, Serno, Sername,Qty,Unit,Lastprice,Vendorname,Department,Section,Category) VALUES" +
                        "(@Itemid,@Serno,@Sername,@Qty,@Unit,@Lastprice,@Vendorname,@Department,@Section,@Category)" + "SET IDENTITY_INSERT foalmaster OFF;";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemid", Itemid);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serno", Serno);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sername", Sername);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", Unit);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastprice", Lastprice);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendorname", Vendorname);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", Department);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Section);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errormsg = ex.Message;
                return;
            }



            Successmsg = "Item Added Successfully To Master List!";

            Itemid = "";
            Serno = "";
            Sername = "";
            Qty = "";
            Unit = "";
            Lastprice = "";
            Vendorname = "";
            Department = "";
            Section = "";
            Category = "";


            ModelState.Clear();
        }   
    }
}
```

2. Add Item.cshtml

```
@page
@model PCERM.Pages.Add_ItemModel
@{
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto p-1">
        <h3 class=" mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center pb-1">Add Item to FOAL Master List</h3>

        @if(Model.Errormsg.Length>0)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
               <strong>@Model.Errormsg</strong>
               <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        }
        else if (Model.Successmsg.Length>0)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
               <strong>@Model.Successmsg</strong>
               <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        }

       <form method="post">
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for ="Itemid"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Itemid" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Itemid" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Serno"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Serno" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Serno" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Sername"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Sername" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Sername" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Qty"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Qty" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Unit"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Unit" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Lastprice"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Lastprice" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Lastprice" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Vendorname"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Vendorname" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Vendorname" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Department"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-select" asp-for="Department" asp-items="Model.DepartmentList">
                 
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Department" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Section"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-select" asp-for="Section" asp-items="Model.SectionList">
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Section" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" asp-for="Category"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-select" asp-for="Category" asp-items="Model.CategoryList">
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Category" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            
           <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="offset-sm-4" col-sm-8>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item to Master List</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Masterlist.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Master_List
{
    public class MasterlistModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Masterlistinfo> listmasteritems = new();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PCERM;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString)) 
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM foalmaster";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new(sql, connection)) 
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                        {
                            while (reader.Read()) 
                            {
                                Masterlistinfo Masterlistinfo = new();
                                Masterlistinfo.Itemid = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                Masterlistinfo.Serno = reader.GetString(1);
                                Masterlistinfo.Sername = reader.GetString(2);
                                Masterlistinfo.Qty = reader.GetString(3);
                                Masterlistinfo.Unit = reader.GetString(4);
                                Masterlistinfo.Lastprice= reader.GetString(5);
                                Masterlistinfo.Vendorname= reader.GetString(6); 
                                Masterlistinfo.Department= reader.GetString(7);
                                Masterlistinfo.Section= reader.GetString(8);
                                Masterlistinfo.Category= reader.GetString(9);

                                listmasteritems.Add(Masterlistinfo);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Masterlistinfo
    {
        public int Itemid { get; set; }
        public string Serno { get; set; } = "";
        public string Sername { get; set; } = "";
        public string Qty { get; set; } = "";
        public string Unit { get; set; } = "";
        public string Lastprice { get; set; } = "";
        public string Vendorname { get; set; } = "";
        public string Department { get; set; } = "";
        public string Section { get; set; } = "";
        public string Category { get; set; } = "";
                
    }


}
```

4. Masterlist.cshtml

```
@page
@model PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Master_List.MasterlistModel
@{
}
<br>
<h2> Item Master List</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Serial No</th>
            <th>Serial Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Last Purchased Price</th>
            <th>Vendor Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var thing in Model.listmasteritems)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@thing.Itemid</td>
                <td>@thing.Serno</td>
                <td>@thing.Sername</td>
                <td>@thing.Qty</td>
                <td>@thing.Unit</td>
                <td>@thing.Lastprice</td>
                <td>@thing.Vendorname</td>
                <td>@thing.Department</td>
                <td>@thing.Section</td>
                <td>@thing.Category</td>
                <td style=" white-space:nowrap">
                    <a class=" btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="">Update</a>
                    <a class=" btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }


    </tbody>
</table>
```

5. SQL query to create table *foalmaster*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[foalmaster] (
    [itemid]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [serno]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [sername]    VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [qty]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [unit]       VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [lastprice]  INT           NOT NULL,
    [vendorname] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [department] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [section]    VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [category]   INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([itemid] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether there is an exception thrown in the `OnGet` of your `MasterlistModel ` class/model. It seems like an exception will just get swallowed here and might be easy to miss.

Comment: `Serno = reader.GetString(1);` but `serno` is defined as `[serno] INT  NOT NULL,` Makes sure all records in the result set are read with the appropriate methods. If you need to convert them to strings later you can but don't try and do it here!

Comment: @phuzi Thank You So Much!! Solved my issue...Turns out it was basically a type mismatch among table and my c# code